# $D(t) = 100 - 95 (\frac{3}{5})^t$ challenging math problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A researcher is interested in the buying behaviour (an indicator of demand) of a selected group of party pill users. In a controlled experiment, a new legalised party pill is put on to the market. Based on previous data, the researcher suggests the following demand model: $D(t) = 100 - 95 (\frac{3}{5})^t$, $t$ is measured in the number of weeks it has been on the market, and $D(t)$ represents the percentage of the selected group wanting to buy the party pill after $t$ weeks ($D(t) = 87$, means $87\%$ of the selected group).

a) Practically interpret what the model suggests about $D(t)$ when $t = 0$.

b) How many days after the party pill is released does the model D(t) suggest that the demand for the party pill will first exceed $50\%$ of the selected group?

c) After a short time though, the researcher has to revise his model because real data received from the outlet stores suggests that approximately 11 hours after the party pill went on the market, $50\%$ of the selected group had purchased it. He revises his model to $D(t) = 100 - 95(A)t$. Find A and hence write the new model.

d) Give a practical interpretation of the asymptotic behaviour for the function $D(t)$
you found in c.

Comment: Question: on part c do you mean $(A)^t$???

Comment: Yes! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

a) If $t=0$ then only $5\%$ of the group will buy it. Practically speaking they will stick with their previous product.

b)

Let $D(t)=50$, then:

$$50=100-95(\frac{3}{5})^t$$
$$50=95(\frac{3}{5})^t$$
$$\frac{50}{95}=(\frac{3}{5})^t$$
$$\log_{3/5}{\frac{50}{95}}=t$$
$$t\approx 1.256502$$

Approximately 9 days.

c) Let $D(t)=50$ and $t=\frac{11}{168}$ ($11$ hours) then:
$$50=100-95(A)^{\frac{11}{168}}$$
$$\frac{50}{95}=(A)^{\frac{11}{168}}$$
$$A=(\frac{50}{95})^{\frac{168}{11}}$$
$$A \approx 0.00005529327$$
So the new model is $D(t)=100-95(0.00005529327)^t$

d) Naturally, there can never be $100\%$ of people ALL buying the same product when there are alternatives on offer. So the number will only APPROACH $100\%$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help, John! I do have one question though. Where are you getting the 168 from? 11/168.

Comment: $168=24 \cdot 7$ (the number of hours in a week). So $\frac{11}{168}$ is the value of $t$ $11$ hours after their product was introduced.

Comment: Oh I see! Gotcha :)

Comment: Would you by any chance know part d?